# Testing Node.js data processing

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs

I'm trying to read some data from a locally stored JSON file, process it into separate JS objects, and append it to a queue. For the life of me, I can't find a way to test that my parsing function is working. To test that it works, I'm trying to pull the data from the local JSON file, and and print it to console. I think there's something conceptually that I don't understand, or a method to test this that I don't know of.

I cannot run the `fs` module in the browser even with Browserify. Firefox tells me that `createReadStream` is not a function.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 700px;"></div>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" /> -->
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="parse.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

**parse.js**

```
//Assume JSON output = {attack source, attack destination, attack type}

//Required modules
//@ts-ignore: undeclared module
const watchStream = require('fs-watch-stream')
const es = require('event-stream')
const stream = require('JSONStream')
const fs = require('fs');

//Create websocket to receive json data instead?
//Save for later
//https.createServer(attacks).listen(9090)


function initial (){

    var filepath = 'sample.json';
    //Creates readable stream for JSON file parsing
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath, { encoding: 'utf8' }),
        parser = stream.parse('*.');

    //Send read data to parser function
    return stream.pipe(parser);
}

initial()
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }));
```

**sample.json**

```
{
  "employees": {
    "employee": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "Tom",
        "lastName": "Cruise",
        "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Maria",
        "lastName": "Sharapova",
        "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/Maria-Sharapova.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "firstName": "Robert",
        "lastName": "Downey Jr.",
        "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/Robert-Downey-Jr.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is your clinet (Browser) or the server (NodeJs)?? Are you trying to open a file in browser and do something on it???

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to involve the browser; just run `node parse.js`. Node.js has `console.log` too, and you will see the output in the console.

If you install `fs-extra`, you can use [`fs.readJson()`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/readJson.md) to get the JSON as an object directly.